# Unable to add new payment processor civicrm settings - payment processor

Tags: wordpress, payment-processor

I am not able to see the "new payment processor" button on CiviCRM settings - payment processor.

I am using working on the integration of CVCRM to word press.

[image]
Thanks
Umesh Kumar

Comment: can append &action=browse to url?